# Java, Code Folding using Coffee Bytes for Eclipse 2022 and higher versions

Tags: eclipse, java-8, java-11, folding, code-folding

When I was using Eclipse 2018-12 (Java 8) I could use Coffee-Bytes plugin for Code Folding.
Coffee-Bytes plugin is rally awesome, but recently I have found that I can use Eclipse 2022 based on JDK 11 (It needs JDK-11 for installing), but I can config that in properties to JDK 8 (1.8) for writing Java 8 in the last version of Eclipse, How perfect, isn't it?!

[Eclipse Code Folding using Coffee Bytes](https://itekblog.com/code-folding-in-eclipse-tutorial/)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4XXp.png)

However, Coffee-Bytes plugin, doesn't work with Eclipse 2022 or any version of Eclipse which compatible with JDK 11 (higher than 8) and just works on Eclipse until to 2018-12 version! Opss...

My problem is,
How can I use The Coffee-Bytes plugin in Eclipse 2022 for Code Folding?

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question.